# Script blocked due to mime type mismatch

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, mime-types, marketo

It was reported to me this morning that one our marketo landing pages was not displaying properly in IE. When I checked the page none of the css or js was loading, so it's pretty much an empty page with a few images.

[Link to landing page](http://pages.vistex.com/MIDEM_Music_Ally.html)

Using dev tools in IE I noticed the error:

```
SEC7112: Script from http://pages.vistex.com/js/forms2/polyfills/placeholder/placeholder.css was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

I'm using IE9 the browser seems to go into IE 9 Compatibility View with IE7 Standards. We do have a group policy forcing compatibility view on our domain on our network.

Could this just be an internal network error? Or is this error firing for all users. I was able to check the page in IE11 off our network and it looks fine.